# Simple html DOM how to get src inside <source> inside specific div?

Tags: php, html, css, simple-html-dom

I have a page from where i need to get .mp4 file which is located inside  on a specific

Here is source of the page from where i need to extract link of .mp4 file.

```
<div class="videoPlayer">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var sVideoErrorMessage = "<p style='margin-top:170px; text-align:center; font-size:16pt; font-weight:bold;'>You need the latest Flash player to see this video.<br><br><a rel='nofollow' href='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' style='text-align:center; font-size:16pt; font-weight:bold;'>Click here to get Adobe Flash player</a></p>";
                var bIsIpad         = false;

                function videoPoster() {
                                        var style_padding = (490 - 345.66666666667) / 2;

                    var playerInnerHTML = '<div id="posterHolder">';
                    playerInnerHTML += '    <div id="html5_vid">';
                    playerInnerHTML += '        <img src="http://img03.domainname.com/_thumbs/0000430/0430303/0430303_007i.jpg" width="582" alt="" id="vidImgPoster" /><a id="playBtn" href="javascript:;" onclick="startPlayer()"></a>';
                    playerInnerHTML += '        <span id="lb">loading movie...</span>';
                    playerInnerHTML += '    </div>';
                    playerInnerHTML += '</div>';
                    document.getElementById('_flv_player').innerHTML  = playerInnerHTML;

                    document.getElementById("html5_vid").innerHTML = "<video x-webkit-airplay='allow' id='html5_video' style='margin-top:" + style_padding + "px;' width='610' preload='auto' height='345.66666666667' controls onerror='cantPlayVideo()' " +
                            "<source src='http://videos.mp4.domainname.com/_videos_t4vn23s9jc5498tgj49icfj4678/0000430/_mp4/0430303.mp4?47aac1f74dca44b0626f9a59c221d75c6c0ad5a608ab8ed18241691fb9f72b19848d7f8a5b6c792e9b4beb72db7731038690fb39d4b4c5083c32fdda32c63370a178cc090ea9ba2c3b7f77d9722898ac9bea1210f3b15ab2265133db172d7a529598ea44320dfa43a7e3f99c5f17c54e468f66964f57e7e019813aae9eef404e5c7db09de772602b19b8800e9f63fa37dcee4c164e71a1da7d2b598e117f15caf7ef9e5700' type='video/mp4'>" +
                            "<p style='margin-top:170px; text-align:center; font-size:16pt; font-weight:bold;'>You need the latest Flash player to see this video.<br><br><a rel='nofollow' href='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' style='text-align:center; font-size:16pt; font-weight:bold;'>Click here to get Adobe Flash player</a></p>" +
                            '</video><div id="vidPoster" class="hidden"><img src="http://img03.domainname.com/_thumbs/0000430/0430303/0430303_007i.jpg" width="584" alt="" id="vidImgPoster" style="top:'+ style_padding +'px" /><a id="playBtn" href="javascript:;" onclick="startPlayer()"></a><span id="lb">loading movie...</span></div>';
                    var vid     = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

                    if (vid != null && 'msie' != $.browser.name) {
                        vid.play();
                        vid.pause();
                    }
                                    }
            </script>
                </div>
```

So from all this code i need to extract this

```
http://videos.mp4.domainname.com/_videos_t4vn23s9jc5498tgj49icfj4678/0000430/_mp4/0430303.mp4
```

This is inside  src and maybe you can notice that behind .mp4 is a questionmark with bunch of codes, i don't need that also i just need direct link to .mp4 file.

Is it possible to extract it?

I already set simplehtmldom on my localhost folder and tried few things from tutorial and it's working but i don't know how to extract this.

I need this to have on my php page.

Comment: You mean you want the `src` attribute from the `<source>` in the resulting html? Or do you only have this source code, as text?

Comment: Yes i want src attribute from the <source> in resulting html

Comment: Then the answer is something simple like `var src = document.querySelector('#html5_vid video).src; src = src.slice(0, src.indexOf('?'));`

Comment: Maybe stupid question but why var src = isn't that jacascript? i need it to use in php code. all the examples point like $dom->find so im little confused?

Comment: PHP? Then why didn't you say so? You never said there was supposed to be a PHP solution. You didn't mention PHP. The question wasn't tagged PHP. It was tagged Javascript, and the source code you showed contained Javascript. I'm a little confused too.

Comment: Yes sorry those are tags auto suggested by site. Im building some plugin for wordpress so i need php solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those times where it's ok to use regex:

```
if(!preg_match("/<source src='([^?']*)/", $str, $m)) die('no match!');
$src = $m[1];
```

The reason being that it's not really html, it's javascript. No html parser will do a good job with this.

Comment: This is what i need, but i have another problem, actual domain name from where allowed videos are is different from one in source i get. so i need to remove that to i just need to have link to video like this _videos_t4vn23s9jc5498tgj49icfj4678/0000430/_mp4/0430303.mp4 Any help since i don't have a clue about preg_match.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but it sounds like something that should be in a new question.

Comment: I asked in another question and already found solution with parse_url now i just need to test it if it works in various url's.